# XRRichText doesn't render Html tables

Tags: html, devexpress, xtrareport

I use a DevExpress XtraReport to build reports. I create in run-time the List of report's records. One field is XRRichText and contains simple markup:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:40%;">value0</td>
        <td style="width:30%;">value1</td>
        <td style="width:30%;">value2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It's bind by next way:

```
XRRichTextControl.DataBindings.Add("Html", bindingSource, "HtmlField");
```

And finally it's render table in something like this:

```
value0 value1 value2
```

But I need a table, not a flat text, how can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Jo,

Tables aren't yet supported in the current version of XtraReports, sorry. For now, you can only track the following suggestion:

Support tables - http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/DS53152.aspx

Comment: It's a pity that there is no tables support = (

Comment: Hi Jo,

Yes, it is unfortunate but the suggestion has been accepted and may get implemented in the future. I recommend tracking that suggestion so you know when it is updated. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this!

add `border="1"` to table